# Provide chromedriver.exe in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I built a lambda Function in java and Gradle with a Selenium Test. This test needs a chromedriver.exe File. How can I provide this File in the Zip-folder for Lambda?
Or is it the better way to provide it in an S3-Bucket?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you use WebDriverManager, that way you dont need to use the driver.exe anymore. Please refer to my answer in this post on how to do that
[WebDriverManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566186/can-we-add-drivers-in-selenium-as-maven-depandancies/50587347#50587347)

Comment: Now I get the following Exception:

"errorMessage": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory: /home/sbx_user1059/.m2/repository/webdriver",
  "errorType": "io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.handleException(WebDriverManager.java:475)",
    "io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:458)",
    "io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.handleException(WebDriverManager.java:472)",
    
...

Comment: The following line is the problem:

WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

Comment: what happens when you run it locally ? do you get the same exception?

Comment: I get the exception only with aws lambda... locally it works great

Comment: So your Expcetion is telling that  /home/sbx_user1059/.m2/repository/webdriver is not a directory , that means that it's trying to pull this path to get the maven dependencies. Can  you share how your are doing things in lambda. I can't really help if there are no more information