# How can I insert path (environmental variable) for geckodriver in google colab?

Tags: selenium, firefox, path, google-colaboratory, geckodriver

I want to run selenium in Google Colab through gecko driver, but it told me: executable needs to be in PATH

I uploaded firefox and gecko driver in Google Colab and copied gecko driver's path. The code worked well on my PC.

firefox and gecko driver in google clob, but an error occurred.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


driver =  webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'content/geckodriver.exe')

WebDriverException: Message: 'content/geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I want gecko driver should be known by selenium in Google Colab environment.

Comment: Are you checked your syncing conditions between your selenium version and your Firefox version? Are they compatible?

Comment: Yes. It is correct.

Comment: I tried your code on my PC and it worked well. What's your problem?

Comment: I know. As I already said in my question, it worked correctly on my PC, but I cannot run it on GoogleColab.

Comment: Please, check this URL:
https://qiita.com/Naritoshi/items/1a306f7d47c6d731c42c

Comment: I saw it before. Explanation of this link is based on Ubuntu, not the Windows. I'm running based on the Windows platform.

Answer (score 4):

I made a gist on how to use chrome+selenium on Colab here.

https://gist.github.com/korakot/5c8e21a5af63966d80a676af0ce15067

The key is to copy the driver to PATH (here is /usr/bin)

`!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin`

You can try copy your gecko driver there as well. But you cannot use the `exe` file which only run on Windows.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver': 'chromedriver'