# Runnning Selenium on Colab is broken again

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory

I had been able to use selenium like a month ago, using the method a trivial search on this site like [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046454/how-can-we-use-selenium-webdriver-in-colab-research-google-com?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63900884/webscraping-with-selenium-without-browser?noredirect=1&lq=1). But none of these work anymore, nor does changing from ubuntu to debian. I am at a loss at how I can use selenium with google colab now? I would appreciate your ideas. Thank you.

I tried to use the changes made in the previusly linked answers, none of them worked.