# How to install a web driver in Google Colab to work with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

I want to run Selenium in Google Colab (Selenium: 4.8.2, Python: 3.8.10). But when installing the web driver I get an error:

`AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'`

My code:

```
!pip install selenium

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

path = "drive/MyDrive/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(path))
```

My browser: Google Chrome 110.0.5481.178

Driver: Latest stable release: ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77

OS: Windows 10

Why does such an error occur? What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046454/how-can-we-use-selenium-webdriver-in-colab-research-google-com) how you worked with selenium in CoLab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from this blog and it worked!

https://nariyoo.com/python-how-to-run-selenium-in-google-colab/
[Python] How to run selenium in Google Colab

```
!pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')

import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

# setup chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') # ensure GUI is off
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# set path to chromedriver as per your configuration
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

# set the target URL
url = "put-url-here-to-scrape"

# set up the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Now you can easily import other selenium library that you need and the driver will be worked. I hope it help!